# How do I use Do Until with a previous Try Catch Exception to avoid running the code twice

Tags: vb.net

i have this line of code to catch an exception if a letter is inputed, or if it is out of rang as a number, but I have added WHEN to avoid catching numberical data. Now how can I use an exception error to use it before my case statement in order to avoid running the code twice, cause once the case codes has been through it will run a clear txtbox which is already taken care by the try catch, don`t if thats clear for you but i understand it. here is the code in parts...

```
    Try
        'Integer Levels: intLvls is egual to the assigned text box, the first one from
        'the top, this line of code allow the user input to be captured into a variable.
        intLvls = txtBoxLvl.Text
    Catch ex As Exception When IsNumeric(intLvls)
        ErrTypeLetterFeild1()
    Finally
        analysingvalues1()
    End Try
```

WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO: Use loop until refencing the exception error to avoid running this following part of the code:

```
 Private Sub analysingvalues1()
    Do Until IsNumeric (ex As Exception)<------how do i do this???

    Loop
```

the case part of the code:

```
Select Case intLvls
        'User is prompt with the following label: lblLvl "Level of salespersons 1 - 4"
        'to make a choice from 1 to 4 as available values.
        Case 1 To 4
            'This line regulates the range of acceptable values, first textbox: must be egual
            'or higher than 1 and lower or egual to 4. Upon such rules a validation becomes
            'correct and is directed to the isValidCalculation sub.
            isValidCalculation()
        Case Is < 1
            ErrType1NumberRangeFeild()
        Case Is > 4
            ErrType1NumberRangeFeild()
        Case Else
            If txtBoxLvl.Text = "" Then
                ErrTypeClear1()
            Else
                If Not IsNumeric(txtBoxLvl.Text) Then
                    ErrType1NumberRangeFeild()
                Else
                    ErrTypeLetterFeild1()
                    ErrTypeClear1()
                End If
            End If
    End Select 'Ending choices.
End Sub
```

Tks for your help!

Comment: Put 'Option Strict On' at the top of your code or set it in the project's properties.  What is the type of intLvls?

Answer (score 3):

If you turn on Option Strict this:

```
intLvls = txtBoxLvl.Text
```

Will no longer compile. This should tell you that your doing something smelly.

**Turn on Option Strict**

The correct solution is not to blindly allow the runtime to cast string to int for you, and catch the exceptions.

When you are converting string user input to an integer, bad input is *not* an exceptional condition, it is something you should expect and code defensively for.

I would rewrite it to something like this:

```
    'Integer Levels: intLvls is egual to the assigned text box, the first one from
    'the top, this line of code allow the user input to be captured into a variable.

    if integer.TryParse( txtBoxLvl.Text, intLvls )
        analysingvalues1()
    else
        ErrTypeLetterFeild1()
```

Edit - As pointed out by Chris below, I meant Option Strict. I recommend using but Explicit and Strict, and Infer if available.

Comment: I think you mean Option Strict?